# How to normalize an array with rounding the result (python, numpy, scipy)

Tags: python, numpy, normalize

Further not the correct code.
How to make it correct, short and beautiful?

```
def normalize_weights(weights, threshold=0.01):
    total = sum(weights)
    result = [x / total for x in weights]
    result = [int((1.0 / threshold) * x) * threshold for x in result]
    result[-1] = 1.0 - sum(result[:-1])
    print(result)
    result[-1] = int((1.0 / threshold) * result[-1]) * threshold
    print(result)

normalize_weights([1.0, 1.0, 1.0])
[0.33, 0.33, 0.33999999999999997]
[0.33, 0.33, 0.34]  # ok

normalize_weights([1.0, 3.0, 1.0])
[0.2, 0.6, 0.19999999999999996]
[0.2, 0.6, 0.19]  # wrong
```

thanks in advance

edit: The sum of the result should be equal 1.0

Comment: what is the desired output of the second call of the function?

Comment: [0.2,0.6,0.2] The sum of the result should be equal 1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = numpy.array([1.0,3.0,1.0])
normalized_a = numpy.round(a/numpy.linalg.norm(a,1.0),2)
# [0.2,0.6,0.2]
```

maybe?

```
a = numpy.array([1.0,1.0,1.0])
normalized_a = numpy.round(a/numpy.linalg.norm(a,1.0),2)
# [0.33,0.33,0.33]
```

if you want to have 2 decimal places and force to `1.0` just fix it

```
normalized_a[0] += 1.0 - numpy.sum(normalized_a) # we could just as easily fix the -1 index ...
```

Comment: The sum of the result should be equal 1.0

Comment: It looks great. Thank you.